# Correctness of "Thank you for your time and looking forward to your response."

Tags: word-usage

I see "Thank you for your time and looking forward to your response." in my co-workers emails. Is it correct? What about "Merry Christmas and wishing you well."

Comment: The latter won't be correct until later in the year.

Answer (score 1):

> "Thank you for your time and looking forward to your response."

For informal discourse, such as may appear in intra-office memos, I would say that this is fine.  There is a stylistic problem when considering the two clauses about the conjunction, though.  The verb for the first is in the simple present, whereas that for the second is in the progressive.  This leads to the rather awkward:

*"[I] thank you for your time and [am] looking forward to your response."*

While the meaning is clear, this kind of writing should not be used in more formal discourse.  Stylistically, the verbs for the independent clauses related by a coordinating conjunction should be in the same tense and aspect (parallelism).

> "Merry Christmas and wishing you well."

Again, I would say that this is fine for informal discourse.

Avoid for more formal writing though for the same reason.  The two independent clauses are not parallel:

*"[I wish you a] Merry Christmas and [I am] wishing you well."

Better:

*"[I wish you] Merry Christmas and best wishes for a Happy New Year."*

Comment: Even for informal, I would make the verbs agree or would drop the "and" to make two phrases: "thanks for your time.  Looking forward to your response."

Comment: I agree that if it is important to maintain the difference in the verb forms, then separate sentences are advisable.

Answer (score 1):

If we wrote each of the clauses in the first sentence as separate sentences and added the implied subject, "I," we'd have:

1. I thank you for your time.
2. I am looking forward to your response.

In case (1), we only had to add "I," whereas in case (2), we had to add "I am." As such, I don't believe the sentence is correct. I think that this issue would, however, go mostly unnoticed in a colloquial conversation.

The second sentence presents a similar issue:

1. I wish you a merry Christmas.
2. I am wishing you well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common question in my ESL email writing classes.  For some reason, students are very eager to be informal in emails.  The usual reason is they want to sound "friendly."

Formal writing just means clear communication.  It is not unfriendly or heavy or serious or meant to express anger or hide true feelings, etc.

Students also feel that in informal writing, the usual rules of grammar don't apply.  That's not true.  Subjects such as "I" are usually omitted but otherwise, the rules apply.

Your example phrases are standard email endings.  Pick one of my suggestions and stick with it.

"Thanks.  Look forward to hearing from you."

"Thanks.  Looking forward to hearing from you."

"Wish you a merry Christmas."

The last example can be used for all holidays, "Wish you a happy thanksgiving." or "Wish you a happy Memorial Day."

To be frank, there is nothing wrong with saying "Thank you.  I look forward to hearing from you."  It is not less friendly or make you sound old fashioned, etc.  It makes you a good communicator.